# Google Chrome's connection attempt to 127.0.0.1 was rejected

Tags: google-chrome, oracle10g, localhost

I am using "**Oracle Database 10g Express Edition**" and I am trying to start Database homepage but Google Chrome or Firefox are showing errors.
 Note: **I am not using any proxy.**
The message shown in Chrome is

> Google Chrome's connection attempt to 127.0.0.1 was rejected. The
>   website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.

What are the possible solutions?

Comment: Are you using `http` or `https`; and the right port number? Did you try with the server's external IP address, rather than localhost? I'm assuming your browser is on the same machine as the DB, otherwise using localhost wouldn't make much sense amyway...

Comment: @AlexPoole i tried using both http and https. i am using the provided shortcut "Go To Database Home Page". I am on a learning phase so i have DB on my machine using localhost.

Comment: What port is it trying to connect to - what's the actual URL in your address bar? Is anything listening on that port (which you can check with `netstat`)? Is your listener running, and if you're on Windows are all the Oracle services running?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it as follows:

When opening Tomcat Application Manager from the shortcut on the Start menu, then it opened the link `http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/html` which caused exactly the same error as you report

All I did was remove the `:8080` from the URL and it worked